# Cake Pattern and Spring Configurer

Tags: spring, scala, configuration, dependency-injection

Spring provides utility [Configurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to resolve placeholders with external configuration data (see the documentation for details). How can I configure my components in a similar way (that is, using external configuration to resolve placeholders) with `Cake Pattern`?

For example:

```
 // properties configuration file

driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dbname=mysql:mydb
user=michael
password=*****

trait JdbcSupport {
  val dataSource:Datasource
  ...
}

trait OrderDAOComponent {self: JdbcSupport =>
  val dao: OrderDAO
  class OrderDAOImpl extends OrderDAO {...} // use the JDBC data source here
}
```

How can I use the properties configuration file to initialize the `OrderDAO` using the `Cake Pattern`?

Answer (score 2):

```
trait XmlConfigJdbcSupport extends JdbcSupport {
  val xmlFile:String
  override val dataSource = readConfigAndReturnDatasource()
}

object MyContext extends OrderDAOComponent with XmlConfigJdbcSupport {
  override val xmlFile = "config.xml"
}
```

`dataSource` should probably be a lazy val to avoid problems with the initialization order.

Comment: I would prefer a general purpose trait `Configurer`, which knows how to read a configuration file and return a value by key.

Comment: In that case you could do this: trait Configurer[A] { def a:A }; trait SomeDao { self: Configurer[DataSource] => ... }; Then you extend Configurer[DataSource] to provide the implementation of how to get a DataSource) and mix that trait with SomeDao.